# Retrieve BLOB from MySQL with vb.net not using picturebox

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This may seem like a trivial question, however I have searched for a decent explanation and tried to decipher this problem myself with little to no success. I wish to retrieve a blob I have stored on my MySql database, render it as an image, and display it as an image in my associated ASPX page. I am not using a picturebox. If there is a resource which I have just not seen, I will accept it as an answer and apologize for the duplicate question. I need no assistance establishing a connection.

Edited: Here's what I've been working with most recently, besides making a file stream to a directory I do not have access to write files to. The error occurs at Image.FromStream(lstr)

```
    Dim Query As String = "Select PIC from USERS where ID = 1"

    Dim adapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter

    adapter.SelectCommand = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(Query, connection)

    Dim Data As New DataTable

    Dim commandbuild As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)

    adapter.Fill(data)


    Dim lb() As Byte = Data.Rows(Data.Rows.Count - 1).Item("PIC")
    Dim lstr As New System.IO.MemoryStream(lb)
    Dim X As Image = Image.FromStream(lstr)
    lstr.Close()

    Return X
```

Comment: And show your `SELECT` MySQL request...

Comment: "_tried to decipher this problem myself with little to no success_" - you should explain what you have tried so that we don't end up suggesting the same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx said that **You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.**

So you have to remove `lstr.Close()`

You can do that after you dispose `lstr` when you not neede it anymore ..

EDITED AGAIN :

Changed this

```
Dim lstr As New System.IO.MemoryStream(lb)
Dim X As Image = Image.FromStream(lstr)
lstr.Close()
```

to

```
Dim lstr As New System.IO.MemoryStream(lb)
Dim X As Image = Image.FromStream(lstr)
Dim X2 As Image = X
x.Dispose
lstr.Close()
```

then you can use X2 as your image

Comment: I'll have to try this a little bit later, but it built properly. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: This fixed the error I was experiencing, but I still get a broken image link. It is trying to retrieve System.Image.Bitmap, and all I've changed is the close statement

Comment: There is no file to retrieve, it's a URI, returns an error. The first method worked, but I'm having difficulty rendering it as an image, which is part of the original question.

Comment: I have it as an image already, I need to display it in an ASPX as per the question

Comment: @JCG isn't that x2 is an image var ?

Comment: what am I supposed to do with it? you can't just load it into the page that way

Comment: @JCG .. I'm only avoiding the error you've got and help you get the image, I can't help you in ASPX cause I just know about VB Winforms ..

Comment: @JCG .. but you can see this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724476/how-to-display-mysql-blob-image-in-asp-net-image-control

Comment: Perfect link! Thank you for all the help @matzone! +1 for persistence!